# meaning of far end and opposite end

Tags: british-english

Can you please tell the meaning of far end and opposite end of the picnic area in the below picture?

[image: map of picnic area]

There is a lot of confusion in filling the answers in no 18, 19 and 20. Even my guess are not working.

1. cars then parked to the left through the gates into the car park, and bikes to the right through the gate opposite
2. cyclist in particular might be feeling thirsty at this point and you can get the drink from  the machine at the end of the bike park, half way to the museum entrance. You can enjoy your drink in the picnic area which is opposite the car park.
3. for anyone who does not have a mobile phone, there are pay phones at the far end of the picnic area,
4. over at the opposite end of the picnic area, across the path are the toilets,
5. next to them and just to the right to the entrance of main museum, is the first aid room,

Source of info: https://youtu.be/7AWBPACJB-0?list=PLxtiwyO2lmaJsGMWKASyxURflFClV0xPu&t=577

Comment: I'd like to try and answer, but I don't know what I'm looking at. What is the context of this whole thing? Am I looking at a map or a signboard? Where am I on the map? Why are there letters on the right that don't appear on the map? What are 1. through 5.? What are the questions for 18, 19, and 20? Please edit your question, and enlarge your screenshot to include important info, rather than requiring us to watch through the video just to understand your question.

Comment: There are 3 correct options among the choices given in the right side listed.

Comment: Also you should read the source of this information in the given link.

Comment: After reading item #1, *cars then parked to the left through the gates into the car park,* it becomes apparent that this is an exercise in futility.  If the author is not familiar with the usage of *into*, why would I assume they have a grasp of *opposite* or *far end*?  I would suggest a whole rewrite, using physical markers.  *The phones are located in the picnic area where the picnic area borders the **Main Walkway/Driveway/Road***.

Answer (score 2):

It would be good to give a little more context, but the meaning of the phrases is thus:

1. The 'far end' is the end farthest from the subject, or the entrance, depending on the context. So one could say, "There is a ticket booth at the entrance, and the ambulance is stationed at the far end of the driveway. This would mean that you see the ticket booth right as you come in, but you have to go all the way down the driveway to get to where the ambulance parks.
2. The opposite end has to do with other side of something from the thing mentioned. So you could say 'the hot dogs are sold right near the dance hall, but you have to buy the drinks at the opposite end of the picnic area."

Comment: added the source of info in the question.

Comment: I take it that the toilets are at the opposite (other) end of the picnic area from the payphones.

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting test, and the context does make a bit of difference here.

Comment: the pay phones if you look at the picture above again, are they available beside (far end) of the picnic area? inside point 19?

Comment: 'The Far End' is 'inside' or 'part of' something. This picture is a bit deceptive in that sense, but, yes, 19.

Comment: So, does that means "over at the opposite end of the picnic area, across the path are the toilets," points to 18 in the image?