# Why is "given" in the beginning of the sentence?

Tags: british-english

The bulk of pottery found at Akrotiri is locally made, and dates from the late fifteenth century BC. It clearly fulfilled a vast range of the settlement’s requirements: more than fifty different types of pots can be distinguished. The pottery found includes a wide variety of functional types like storage jars, smaller containers, pouring vessels, cooking pots, drinking vessels and so on, which all relate to specific activities and which would have been made and distributed with those activities in mind.

Given the large number of shapes produced and the relatively high degree of standardization, it has generally been assumed that most, if not all, of Akrotiri pottery was produced by specialized
craftsmen in a non-domestic context.

**What is the meaning when we write given in the beginning of the sentence?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "taking into account" [Collins definition 5](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/given) or "knowing about" or "considering" ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/given)). It often appears as "Given the fact that..."

Comment: can you explain the sentence started with Given in simple speech?

Comment: @Pankaj: "We know that very many shapes were made, and that they are highly standardized*, so most people have assumed (have thought) that most Akrotiri pottery, or perhaps all of it, was made by 'professional' craftsmen working in special workshops, not at home." *_standardized_ might mean the clay was always exactly 4cms thick. Or their plates were always THIS big. Or they decorated their cups with either stars or circles. (Is that clear? :-)

Comment: @Pankaj: OK. Done.

Comment: Will you please like to give your precious views in this question? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/289394/meaning-of-far-end-and-opposite-end

Answer (score 0):

"Given" is a preposition followed by a noun phrase, meaning "considering". Please refer to the third definition on this page: https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/given